# displaying/accepting one value in number form field (e.g. age) but storing another (e.g. year of birth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I could do the conversions in the edit/update/create controller actions, but is there a more elegant way to do this? When using a collection, it's pretty easy to do with with value_method/display_method. But when I try to do it with just a simple integer input field, value_method/display_method don't seem work, or maybe I'm doing the syntax wrong. I'm also having a surprisingly hard time finding anything about this on google.

Ideally the solution would work both for new and edit, so the user always sees/enters an age value in the form but it's always stored as yob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this at the model level...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :age

  before_save :determine_year_of_birth
  after_find :determine_age

  def determine_year_of_birth
    self.year_of_birth = Date.today.year - age
  end

  def determine_age
    self.age = Date.today.year - year_of_birth
  end

end
```

Comment: I'd prefer doing the conversions in the controller, as that doesn't require defining both age and yob at the model level, which would feel like unnecessary baggage. Since it's a display thing ideally I'd handle it in the view, maybe with a helper method, as can be done with collections. But if it can't be done then the controller is at least closer to the view than the model.

Comment: In my solution, age is not actually defined as a model column, it's an attr_accessor field.  The nice thing about doing it in the model is that it's DRYer... (IMHO).  

And ultimately you want the value WRITTEN to the database table (albeit converted into YOB) so you would need a "convert" method before every save, which really begs for a "before_save" solution. And if you have a "before_save" solution you need the "after_find" to handle the simple case of, say, reading and writing a record in rails console.

Comment: Just to clarify, age is *not* stored in a column in User.

Comment: Sorry, I was aware of the attr_accessor, just didn't think this deserved treatment at the model level since it's really just a display issue. But I accepted the answer, it's a good answer and may be helpful for others. Thank you! I still feel like there must be a "display method" solution, but not going to spend more time on this now :)

Comment: I tried to edit your method names in the method definitions last week, did you see that? As I'm sure you know, they should be determine_year_of_birth and determine_age. The edit didn't stick.